# How to zoom in and out a 3d matplotlib plot using buttons

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a 3d matplotlib graph but the problem is that. I want to manually zoom in and out the whole curve without any change in scaling. I have tried limiting theaxes but it truncates the curve and the whole curve is no more in focus.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

# Create a 3D figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=80)
fig.tight_layout()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.view_init(elev=0, azim=180, vertical_axis='y')

# Define the vertices of the rectangular rod
N_sub = 1000  # Set higher for better resolution; lower for better performance!
vertices = np.concatenate([
    np.array([[x, -100, -100],
              [x, -100, 100],
              [x, 100, 100],
              [x, 100, -100]])
    for x in np.linspace(-10000, 900, N_sub + 1)], axis=0)

# Define the faces of the rectangular rod
offset = (N_sub) * 4
faces = np.concatenate([
    [[0, 1, 2, 3]],
    *[np.array([[3, 0, 4, 7],
                [0, 1, 5, 4],
                [1, 2, 6, 5],
                [2, 3, 7, 6]]) + 4 * x for x in range(0, N_sub)],
    [[0 + offset, 1 + offset, 2 + offset, 3 + offset]]
], axis=0)

# Map the x-coordinate of each face to a color in the colormap
x = np.array([np.mean([vertices[idx, 0] for idx in face]) for face in faces])
norm = plt.Normalize(x.min(), x.max())
cmap = plt.get_cmap("hot")
colors = cmap(norm(x))

# Create a Poly3DCollection object with the vertices, faces, and colors
rect = Poly3DCollection(vertices[faces], alpha=0.9, facecolors=colors)

# Add the rectangular rod to the plot
ax.add_collection3d(rect)

# Set the limits of the x, y, and z axes
ax.set_xlim([-10000, 900])
ax.set_ylim([-200, 200])
ax.set_zlim([-200, 200])

# Add labels to the axes
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_box_aspect([1,50,1])
# Define the zoom in and out functions
def zoom_in(event):
    ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[0] + 100, ax.get_xlim()[1] - 100)
    ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[0] + 20, ax.get_ylim()[1] - 20)
    ax.set_zlim(ax.get_zlim()[0] + 20, ax.get_zlim()[1] - 20)
    plt.draw()

def zoom_out(event):
    ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[0] - 100, ax.get_xlim()[1] + 100)
    ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[0] - 20, ax.get_ylim()[1] + 20)
    ax.set_zlim(ax.get_zlim()[0] - 20, ax.get_zlim()[1] + 20)
    plt.draw()

# Create the zoom in and out buttons
ax_zoomin = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
ax_zoomout = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
button_zoomin = plt.Button(ax_zoomin, 'Zoom in')
button_zoomout = plt.Button(ax_zoomout, 'Zoom out')
plt.show()
```

Here is what I get[image]

And What I want is something like this [image] but extended along x direction without getting zoomed out.

At first I have created two buttons one for zoom in and another for zoom out and tried to change limit dynamically but nothing works.
To make my problem very simple I want to zoom in and out the whole plot just like zooming a picture.

Can we do it using matplotlib? If yes please suggest how to do it.

Thank you so much in advance